# detect the language a post is written in

Tags: multi-language, plugin-polylang

Is there any way to evaluate the language a post/page is written in? I am building a multilingual site and am almost pulling my hair out trying to get the front-end navigation to take the chosen language into account. So far the polylang plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polylang/ has worked fine for everything else.

Comment: What do you mean 'evaluate'? Analyze the text and detect the language? Or get the language assigned when post was created?

Comment: Get the language assigned when the post/page was created. There will be pages written in, say French and Dutch. If my chosen language is Dutch, I don't want links to the pages in French to be visible.

Comment: Simply remove `pll_the_languages()` from templates or delete the `Language Switcher widget`. Depends where it comes from.

Comment: Tried that to no effect, unfortunately. My menus are still not language-specific. The language is ignored especially when browsing content by category, if that helps diagnose the issue.

Comment: If you mean [Custom Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel) you have to create one menu per language. [See Polylang Navigations menus](http://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/setting-up-a-wordpress-multilingual-site-with-polylang/navigations-menus/).

Comment: Thanks to you both, your responses definitely cleared things up a lot for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main language of a post should be saved in a post meta field. There is no way to detect that automatically. Even Google’s heuristics fail regularly with that.

So add a custom field `lang` and check with …

```
$language = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'lang', TRUE );
```

… what language the post was written in.

### Update

Here is a very simple example for a language selector. It will be visible on every post type with a **Publish** metabox.

[image]

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_language', TRUE );
```

… will return the post’s language if available.

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 't5_language_selector' );
add_action( 'save_post', 't5_save_language' );

function t5_language_selector()
{
    print '<div class="misc-pub-section">
        <label for="t5_language_id">Language</label>
        <select name="t5_language" id="t5_language_id">';

    $current = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_language', TRUE );
    $languages = array (
        'en' => 'English',
        'de' => 'Deutsch',
        'ja' => '日本人'
    );

    foreach ( $languages as $key => $language )
        printf(
            '<option value="%1$s" %2$s>%3$s</option>',
            $key,
            selected( $key, $current, FALSE ),
            $language
        );

    print '</select></div>';
}


function t5_save_language( $id )
{
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
        return;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $id ) )
        return;

    if ( ! isset ( $_POST['t5_language'] ) )
        return delete_post_meta( $id, '_language' );

    if ( ! in_array( $_POST['t5_language'], array ( 'en', 'de', 'ja' ) ) )
        return;

    update_post_meta( $id, '_language', $_POST['t5_language'] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is it possible to add the custom field to the pages post_type as well?

Comment: @user27302 See my update. I have added an example.

Comment: You rock! Thanks a million, am definitely on the right track now.

Answer (score 2):

For the rest api, wp-graphql and wp-cli's `wp eval-file` I needed to do

```
wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'language' )[0]->slug
```